# Windows clients will not refresh Linux samba file locally if reading file at intervals <= 10 seconds

Tags: linux, command-line, windows, samba

If I have a windows client read a file on a Linux smb share at an interval <= 10 seconds, the windows client will show incorrect (cached?) information of that file.

I've reproduced this on multiple systems.

Example steps to reproduce:

1) set up linux samba share - for this example, using Debian and installing samba. example:

```
sudo mkdir /test
sudo chmod 777 /test
```

smb.conf addition:

```
[test]    
read only = no    
locking = no    
path = /test/    
guest ok = yes
```

2) Map this directory as a drive in a windows client (this test will use L:)

3) create a file with some text on the samba server

```
nano /test/test.txt
ORIGINAL
```

4) create simple batch file on windows machine to view file every 5 seconds:

```
copy con test.bat
@echo off
cls
:1
type L:\test.txt
timeout 5
goto 1
```

5) run batch file, it should show ORIGINAL every 5 seconds.

6) on linux server, change file contents

```
nano /test/test.txt
CHANGED
```

7) view the running batch file on windows, it will still say "ORIGINAL" every five seconds, and not "CHANGED" as the real file has.

8) terminate the batch file and wait ~ 15 seconds, OR change timeout to something > 10 seconds, and it will update properly.

Hopefully I've explained and outlined how to test this sufficiently.

Can anyone reproduce this behavior and/or suggest how to fix this?

.

.

.

NOTES:

Linux Client > Linux SMB Host shows the proper file content.

Windows Client > Windows SMB Host shows the proper file content.

**It's specifically Windows Client > Linux SMB Host that does not show the proper file content at a refresh interval of <= 10 seconds.**

All Windows flavors I've tested with (Win7, Win10, Server2016) exhibit the same behavior.

I have also tested different protocols on my samba share 'NT1, SMB2, SMB3', and they do not change the behavior.

**NOTE: I believe this is most likely a Windows issue, but I have not received any responses on either technet or superuser in a week.  This should be fairly easy to test, can anyone confirm this behavior or state otherwise?**

Comment: Hi! Maybe is the windows client caching the file. Have you tried to setup a windows file server to see if it behaves the same. I know you need windows, but am just joking. Best solution ever: uninstall windows.

Comment: I have tested this on Server 2016 with the File Server role installed.  The same behavior occurs.

Comment: Ok maybe next step would be to test disabling caching on server side and on client side ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved this by placing

```
oplocks = False
```

in my smb.conf under my share settings.

https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/old/Samba3-HOWTO/locking.html#id2615926

Answer (score 9):

The default values for the relevant settings are:

- `oplocks = yes`
- `kernel oplocks = no`

(See Samba [smb.conf](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html) documentation)

---

You can disable oplocks, as per another [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/426224/50021).

Alternatively, if you are running a Linux O/S with a modern kernel (2.4 or newer), you can leave `oplocks = yes` and **instead** add a line to `smb.conf` to enable kernel oplocks. As per [kernel oplocks (S)](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#KERNELOPLOCKS) section in documentation:

> Kernel oplocks support allows Samba oplocks to be broken whenever a
>   local UNIX process or NFS operation accesses a file that smbd(8) has
>   oplocked. This allows complete data consistency between SMB/CIFS, NFS
>   and local file access

When `oplocks` and `kernel oplocks` are both enabled, you should get good performance (from caching) and cache invalidation when the files are updated.

To enable kernel oplocks, add this line to your Samba configuration file:

```
kernel oplocks = yes
```

Comment: In the first part of your answer you emphasise that `oplocks` should be disabled. In the second part the quotation says enable them along with `kernel oplocks`. Would it be right to suggest your final example should have not only `kernel oplocks = yes` but also `oplocks = yes`?

Comment: @roaima, the default configuration is: `oplocks = yes` and `kernel oplocks = no`. So there is no need to add `oplocks = yes`; we just need to specify the `kernel oplocks` value.

Comment: I was just thinking that maybe since the first part of your question suggests disabling it, it would be worth connecting that in your final proposal.